# Scala Play Framework on Windows NoClassDefFoundError out of the box

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to run the starter scala Play Framework code on my windows machine. I run:

```
git clone https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-starter-example
```

import it into IntelliJ, and type `sbt run` on the command line. It runs the server on port 9000, but when I try to access the page, it fails with a bunch of `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter`. So it fails right out of the box. I don't know if it has to do with me using Windows. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're using `Java 9`

You need to add `--add-modules=java.xml.bind` option to your JVM. For example in Windows you need to go to the folder your project resides at

```
.\sbt-dist\bin
```

and change `set _JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS%` to `set _JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% --add-modules=java.xml.bind` in `sbt.bat`

Comment: on windows you need to edit C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\conf\sbtconfig.txt and add  the --add-modules option as above